# Circle does not draws after using reset function

Tags: function, events, sfml

following code is intended to increment and decrement the radius of circle depending on right/left click.

Two glitches-

1.The circle grows exceptionally if i press & drag my mouse a little.

2.For once if i use the reset button and then drag my mouse , the circle just dissapears.

Where am i doing wrong. Im sure both problems have the same cause.

```
 #include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>


int main()
{
float p=10;
void radiusincrementer(sf::CircleShape &,float);
void resetter(sf::CircleShape&);
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "JNPL PROJECT");
window.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false);
sf::CircleShape circle;
sf::RectangleShape button;
button.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(0, 400));
button.setSize(sf::Vector2f(20, 20));
circle.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(100,100));
circle.setRadius(10);
circle.setFillColor(sf::Color::Cyan);

//Window loop begins
while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {//Event handling

        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
        if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left))
        {
            p *= 2;
            radiusincrementer(circle, p);
        }
        else if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Right))
        {
            p /= 2;
            radiusincrementer(circle, p);
        }

        if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left))
        {
            if ((event.mouseButton.x >= 0 && event.mouseButton.x <= 20) &&
        (event.mouseButton.y >= 400 && event.mouseButton.y <= 420))
                resetter(circle);
        }


    }
    //Event handling ends
    window.clear();
    window.draw(circle);
    window.draw(button);
    window.display();


}
//Window loop ends
return 0;
}

void resetter(sf::CircleShape & chcricle)
{
chcricle.setRadius(10);
chcricle.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(100, 100));
}         //to reset position and radius if rectangle is clicked

void radiusincrementer(sf::CircleShape & chcricle,float x)
{
chcricle.setRadius(x);
    //to increment radius of circle if screen is clicked
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have stated things that you do not like, but you did not elaborate on what your program is supposed to do. Regardless, I will address your glitches:

1. Your using the "isButtonPressed" function which is called every single frame that the button is pressed. So, if your application is running at 30-60 frames a second, then your "radiusincrementer()" function is going to be called 30-60 times per second. Testing for [single button clicks](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/window-events.php) and [continuous button clicks](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/window-inputs.php) (not multiple but simply holding the button) are different.
2. When you did the circle reset, you didn't reset the variable "p".

Delete (or comment out for the time being) all 3 of the if statements that test for a button press and replace them with the following: (then come back and tell me if this was what you were looking for)

```
        if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed)
        {
            if (event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left)
            {
                // Reset the circle by pressing within bounds of rectangle
                if ((event.mouseButton.x >= 0 && event.mouseButton.x <= 20) &&
                    (event.mouseButton.y >= 400 && event.mouseButton.y <= 420))
                {
                    p = 10;
                    resetter(circle);
                }
                // Left clicked somewhere besides the rectangle, so enlarge the circle
                else
                {
                    p *= 2;
                    radiusincrementer(circle, p);
                }
            }
            // Right clicked anywhere, so make the circle smaller
            if (event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Right)
            {
                p /= 2;
                radiusincrementer(circle, p);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes, That what i was looking for.